# Escaping characters full text search PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got the following prepared query:

```
SELECT 
  b.id b.title b.isbn b.description
FROM
  books b
WHERE 
  MATCH(title,subtitle)
  AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0 3
```

I execute this query where the ? is for example "+term*". This is working great, but it fails if someone enters a term with a special character in it (for example "+term@*"). How can I escape this string in **php** so the special characters for full-text-search are properly escaped?

Comment: How about using regular expressions? e.g. `preg_replace('/[^+A-Za-z\-]/', '', '+term@')` would filter out the at `@` sign. It isn't clear what the definition/requirements of the search parameter is.